# The behavior of the Mathf.RoundToInt()

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine

I have a question about the Mathf.RoundToInt()

```
int val = Mathf.RoundToInt(10.5f);
val = Mathf.RoundToInt(9.5f);
val = Mathf.RoundToInt(8.5f);
```

The above generates "10, 10, 8" not "11, 10, 9".

According to the reference manual of Unity, Mathf.RoundToInt() returns "even value" when the 1st decimal place is "5" (e.g. 8.5 -> 8.0).

I would like to know the reason why the Mathf.RoundToInto() return like this, not like normal rounding (e.g. 8.5 ->9.0, 9.5 -> 10.0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even:

> For reasonable distributions of [...] values, the expected (average) value of the rounded numbers is the same as that of the original numbers.

Comment: [As the docs describe](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. The link helped me to understand the reason. So for values including minus sign.

Comment: The link in the answer has changed to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_half_to_even